# Error installing Mezzanine cms on Windows 7

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, python-imaging-library, mezzanine

I am trying to install mezzanine on windows 7 64 bit. I have installed pil for python 2.7 64 bit from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/).

I recreated my virtualenv, but i still get this error

[image]

i know that error is caused by pil but i installed it and it didn't fix it. I have a C++ compiler installed, i do a lot of C++, i have codeblocks and visual studio, so i don't think i need to install mingw or whatever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my personal experience - don't use 64 bit Python. It will create many problems. Use 32 bit version and in most cases you will be fine.